# Effects of maintaining many MobileFirst versions

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We have an iOS and Android app that we deployed to our MFP server v7.0.

I know that maintaining a lot of versions is hard and the user who installed the old versions may not experience the new features if we don't let them install the latest version.

I want to know what are the other implications/effects if we maintain a lot of version in server. Like if it'll take a long time to restart the server or the server might experience downtime.

What is the good number of versions to be maintained as well? If there's any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know what are the other implications/effects if we maintain a lot of version in server. Like if it'll take a long time to restart the server or the server might experience downtime.

Yes, it could take longer for the server to start if you maintain a lot of resources, I would say this is expected. It's natural.

You will want to look at the following doc: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/learn-more/scalability-and-hardware-sizing-7-1/

> What is the good number of versions to be maintained as well? If there's any.

This is really up to your development, marketing, etc... You probably want to always have your customers on the latest, so you could play with 2-3 versions and Remote Disable those you decide to not support anymore.